# How to ensure data exists in redux store before loading route when using direct link?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using react-redux and react-router
When the app first loads it dispatches an action that populates the store from the database. This is done in the root component. After that there is a basic react router setup:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <MainView />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/product/:id">
        <SingleProduct />
      </Route>
      <Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

The SingleProduct uses the id to retrieve the product from the redux store that was populated earlier.

This works fine. However if I type the url into the browser directly, the store does not have time to populate and I get a product not found. How can I ensure the store has been populated before loading the SingleProduct component?

Comment: I have faced this so many times, what you have to do is add a conditional that does not load the whole app until the data does not fill in the redux store

Comment: @sairaj but how can I test to see if the store has been filled? Do I set a flag of some kind?

Comment: yes you are correct, set a state of loading, this is important **initial state of loading should be true** so that your app starts as loading `true`, and after the data fetching and your store is filled then setLoading to `false` you can show your company logo, or just `Loading...` when your app loads

Comment: The pattern I typically use is to check on the page if the data is available from the store. If it is, cool, render it. If it is not, then make the request to fetch it and conditionally render some "loading" UI until the state is populated. It's basically the same thing as what @sairaj suggests, just in a different location I believe, a specific route component versus the entire app.

Comment: @DrewReese but since the initial dispatched action is already populating the entire state does it not make more sense to somehow wait for that to finish rather then initiating another request?

Comment: Depends. Sometimes you don't need to fetch and populate every part of state. Some data is transient so you don't want to cache it for long in the app. If you hold on just a page and fetch that page's data on-demand then you can cut down waiting for only the relevant data the user is trying to access.